# How do I find value in the field "key1, key2, key3" in the example I provided using PostgresQL assuming the value is not known

Tags: postgresql

```
{
  "KEY1": {
    "NEW_SIZE": 9,
    "NEW_VALUE": 1
   },
  "KEY2": {
    "AGE": 35,
    "LAST_NAME": "DOE",
    "FIRST_NAME": "JOHN",
    "MIDDLE_NAME": null,
    "BIRTH_MONTH_INT": 9
  },
  "KEY3": {
    "NEW_SIZE": 11,
    "NEW_VALUE": 5
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that a single value in a column of a table? What data type is that column? What is the result you want?

Comment: It's part of a jsonb field in a table. I want to be able to write a query to select the value in that field where key1 is not known. (ex select test -> 'key1' ->> 'NEW_SIZE' as N_SIZE from example;) Thanks for your help

Comment: It's not valid JSON is it? You have key "KEY2" repeated twice

Comment: Key2 should not have been repeated twice although I think you can have multiple entries of the same value in that field.

Comment: You are correct Richard Huxton. That key cannot be repeated twice. It only uses the last entry. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Once I was corrected by JSONB, I was able to use

```
SELECT jsonb_object_keys(contents::jsonb) as data   
  FROM example 
 WHERE id = 1;
```

This displayed the values key1, key2, key3 as data so I could display any value in those fields.

Comment: I think you got your terminology wrong. `key1`, `key2` etc are the *keys* of the object, the property *values* are `{"new_size": …}`  etc. Finding the values when you know the keys is trivial (you demonstrated that in your comment, using `->`), finding them when you don't know the keys requires `jsonb_object_keys`. You might want to rephrase your question to be less confusing.